# Unable to store values in a nested Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am trying to store movie ratings by users in a Dictionary. The file from which the data is acquired is of the form

> UserID   |   MovieID   |   Rating  |    Timestamp

They are tab separated values

```
        //Take the first 100 lines from the file and store each line as a array element of text 
        string[] text = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@File path).Take(100).ToArray();

        //extDic[username] - [moviename][rating] is the structure

        Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,double>> extDic=new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,double>>();
        Dictionary<string, double> movie=new Dictionary<string,double>();
        foreach(string s in text)
        {
            int rating;
            string username=s.Split('\t')[0];
            string moviename=s.Split('\t')[1];
            Int32.TryParse(s.Split('\t')[2], out rating);
            movie.Add(moviename,rating);
            if (extDic.ContainsKey(username))
            {   
                //Error line
                extDic[username].Add(moviename, rating);
            }
            else
            {
                extDic.Add(username, movie);
            }
            movie.Clear();
        }
```

I get the following error "An item with the same key has already been added" on the error line. I understand what the error is and have tried to solve it by checking with an if statement. However that doesn't solve it.

Also, I wonder if there is a significant of movie.clear()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be caused by the fact that you are using the variable `movie` as a value for all the entries in the `extDic` dictionary. `movie` is nothing but a reference, so when you are doing a `movie.Clear()` you are clearing all the values from `extDic`.

You could entirely remove the variable `movie` and replace it with a fresh instance of `new Dictionary<string, double>()`

```
string[] text = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@File path).Take(100).ToArray();

//extDic[username] - [moviename][rating] is the structure

Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,double>> extDic=new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,double>>();   
foreach(string s in text)
{
  int rating;
   //split only once
   string[] splitted = s.Split('\t');

  //UPDATE: skip the current line if the structure is not ok
  if(splitted.Length != 3){
      continue;
  }

  string username=splitted[0];
  string moviename=splitted[1];
  Int32.TryParse(splitted[2], out rating);

  //UPDATE: skip the current line if the user name or movie name is not valid
  if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(moviename)){
      continue;
  }


   if(!extDic.ContainsKey(username)){
      //create a new Dictionary for every new user
      extDic.Add(username, new Dictionary<string,double>());
   }
   //at this point we are sure to have all the keys set up
   //let's assign the movie rating
   extDic[username][moviename] = rating;

}
```

Comment: I've modified the code to add some extra validation steps: one for the parsing of one line (`splitted.Length` should be equal to 3) and one for non-null `username` and `moviename`; both of these are used as keys and should not be an empty string or nulls. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

There must be duplicates of that user and movie.

To fix the error, you can use this for your "error line":

```
extDic[username][moviename] = rating;
```

Though there may be other problems afoot.

Comment: That removes the exception but are you sure it fixes the error? I can't see that overriding a previously stored rating by law of nature is the correct thing, maybe it is or maybe the first one is the correct or maybe the average is or maybe it should never happen that a user rates the same movie twice

Comment: @RuneFS, I am not sure (hence my last sentence). I don't have his data, so I can say whether the are duplicates.

Comment: you are stating confidently that you've fixed the error while in your comment stating that you don't know what the error is. Which is my point

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are adding the same dictionary to all users so when two users have rated the same movie you will see this exception

```
int rating;
var result  = from line in text
              let tokens = s.Split('\t')
              let username=tokens[0];
              let moviename=tokens[1];
              where Int32.TryParse(tokens[2], out rating);
              group new {username, Rating=new{moviename,rating}} by username;
```

The above code will give you a structure that from a tree perspective is similar to your own. If you need the lookup capability you can simply call `.ToDictionary`

```
var extDic = result.ToDictionary(x=x.Key, x=>x.ToDictonary(y=>y.moviename,y=>y.rating))
```

The reason why I rewrote it in to LINQ is that it's a lot hard to make those kinds of mistakes using something that's side effect free like LINQ